# using readline in python to print out own line for each word of an input file that is being read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file that contains several lines of text, some of which are blank lines separating indented paragraphs.

I want to print one line of output for each word in the input file using readline() . Could someone provide an example of code that does this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `readline()`; `file` is an iterator over lines by itself. Assuming words are separated by whitespace:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        if words:
            # each line in the output has exactly one word in it
            print("\n".join(words))
```

Comment: Shouldn't your comment be _if a line has any words_, or _if we are not on a blank line_?

Comment: Getting an error with this syntax, Thanks                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/llla/Desktop/Python/c_stuff/c_stuff-primus-try10b.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/llla/Desktop/Python/c_stuff/c_stuff-primus-try10b.py", line 8, in main
    with open(gberg.txt) as file:
NameError: global name 'gberg' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @Primus_Pilus: `filename = "gberg.txt"`. To avoid basic mistakes, you could read some [beginners guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers).